# Visual Basic: Clicking a button on a webpage

Tags: vb.net, bots

I am trying to make a program click the login button of twitch.tv. I have tried many methods but the thing is that I can not find the button ID of that button. I assume that it doesn't have one and I need help clicking it. What commands would I used to click that button if it has no ID? Here is the HTML of that button

```
<div class="buttons"> <button class="primary_button" tabindex="10" type="submit"><span class="">Log In</span>
```

So as you see I have no ID on that button that says Log In. 
Basically what I'm asking is, what is the coding command for clicking buttons without a ID. Buttons like this one with no ID, just a class and a type.

The following is my code so far for typing in my log in info but not hitting the submit button

```
    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_user_login").SetAttribute("Value", "123@gmail.com")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user[password]").SetAttribute("Value", "123@gmail.com")
    'Type = "submit"
    If webpageelement.getattribute("type") = "Log In" Then
        webpageelement.invokemember("click")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: the type="submit", not "Log In"

Comment: "visual" and "basic" <> VB.Net. Please read the description of the tags you're selecting before using them. The proper tag here is "vb.net". "Visual" by itself means "something you can see", and "basic" is either something very simple or a very early programming language, neither of which relate to your question. Using the proper tags means that searching works properly, and that the question gets to the attention of people who know that tag sooner and gets you help more quickly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ieDoc = MyBrowser.Document

        With ieDoc.forms(0)

            .UserName.Value = loguser
            .Password.Value = logpasswrd
            .submit

        End With
```

Comment: loguser = "username" and logpasswrd = "password"